# Creating a divider line on the chart in KendoUI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

So I have a chart and there are 2 series on the chart. I would like to create a red line that goes from the top of the chart to the bottom to divide the two series but I am not getting it to show. I am using the `visual` callback on the series which I have below. Can someone help me figure out how to draw this line? Thanks in advance!

Here is the visual callback

```
valueSeries.visual = (e: AxisLabelVisualArgs) => {
  const bottomRight = e.rect.bottomRight();
  const topRight = e.rect.topRight();
  const path = new drawing.Path({
    stroke: {
      color: '#FF5252',
      width: 2,
    }
  }).moveTo(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y)
    .lineTo(topRight.x, topRight.y);

  const group = new Group();
  group.append(path);
  return group;
}
```

and here is an example of what the chart currently looks like I drew a red arrow where I am trying to get the line to show:

[image]